# what does it mean batch set variable=%variable:~1%

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Can anyone explain what is `:~1%` in the below statement in a batch file? I assigned the value of `%variable` to servername and tried `echo %variable`. I get the same server name as output. Can anyone explain how the statement below works?

```
set variable=%variable:~1%
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is notation for subs string expansion , look at this out put form command line you will understand.

```
C:\>set temp=stackoverflow.com

C:\>echo %temp%
stackoverflow.com

C:\>echo %temp:~5%
overflow.com

C:\>echo %temp:~5,8%
overflow

C:\>
```

if you have not understood , here is syntax (in my words)

```
set variable=%variable:~startingCharector [,OptionalLenghtOfCharctors]%
```

where

`OptionalLenghtOfCharctors` by default it takes remaining characters of string.

Comment: Basically its a substring and split. Now able to understand the script. Thanks Baljeetsingh.

Comment: @user3437439 glad to help you ! , you can help stackoverflow  back by marking the correct answer as green tick.

Answer (score 5):

It's a syntax for substrings from the variable contents, in this case it removes the first character.

See `set /?` for help