# What does %var:~0,4% and %var:.=% mean in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here is my sample batch file code and I really don't know what it does.

```
set TEMPRPSW=%RPSW_VERSION%
set RELVER=%TEMPRPSW:~0,4%
set RELVER=%RELVER:.=%
if %RELVER% GEQ 30 goto :eof
```

Please give me a working sample.

Comment: Type `set /?` into a command prompt window and read the help message very carefully; you will find the description of such syntax intended to expand substrings...

Comment: Great! Very helpful. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does it mean batch set variable=%variable:~1%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505800/what-does-it-mean-batch-set-variable-variable1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That takes a 4 character long substring of TEMPRPSW, starting from character 0.
Meaning, it takes the first 4 characters of TEMPRPSW and puts them in RELVER.

```
set TEMPRPSW=abcdef
set RELVER=%TEMPRPSW:~0,4%
echo %RELVER%       -> will print abcd
```

%VAR:str=% removes str

```
set RELVER=123.456
set RELVER=%RELVER:.=%
echo %RELVER%       -> will print 123456 with no .
```

here is a nice article: https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: What does this line `set RELVER=%RELVER:.=%` doing?

Comment: Great! It helps. :)

Comment: By the way, there's no *need* to go to a web site which may or may not be there at some point in the future. The web site may well be *better* but all the information you need is available to you with a simple `set /?`.

Comment: @paxdiablo +1 precisely. Noted for this. ;)